# Check if directory is empty

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm trying to check if a directory is empty.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QDir Dir("/home/highlander/Desktop/dir");
    if(Dir.count() == 0)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Directory is empty","Empty!!!");
    }
}
```

Whats the right way to check it, excluding `.` and `..`?

Comment: @Blender my bad, just wanna check, if count is a bool ?

Comment: `.count()` should return an integer, so compare it to `0`, not `"0"`.

Comment: well, thats ok, comparing with 1 or 0 is not returning anything whether Dir is empty or not ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, I got the way to do it :)

```
if(QDir("/home/highlander/Desktop/dir").entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllEntries).count() == 0)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this,"Directory is empty","Empty!!!");
}
```

Comment: QDir::AllEntries is not enough for hidden (and possibly system) files. You should check for them as well.

Answer (score 6):

Since Qt 5.9 there is `bool QDir::isEmpty(...)`, which is preferable as it is clearer and faster, [see docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#isEmpty):

> Equivalent to count() == 0 with filters QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, but faster as it just checks whether the directory contains at least one entry.

Answer (score 2):

As Kirinyale pointed out, hidden and system files (like socket files) 
are not counted in highlander141's answer.
To count these as well, consider the following method:

```
bool dirIsEmpty(const QDir& _dir)
{
    QFileInfoList infoList = _dir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::System | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Hidden );
    return infoList.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDesktopServices>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc,argv);

    QDir dir(QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DesktopLocation));

    QStringList list = dir.entryList();
    int count;
    for(int x=0;x<list.count(); x++)
    {
        if(list.at(x) != "." && list.at(x) != "..")
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "This directory has " << count << " files in it.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just check with `dir.count()<3` ?

Comment: @HeyYO: That seems like a way better solution.. Why not answer and take the credit?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just check with;

```
if(dir.count()<3){
    ... //empty dir
}
```

Comment: That's another question. This one is the simplest solution to the question you asked.

Comment: Magic numbers is very bad practice. It may be different on other platforms.